# Scala - Type inference not for Arrays as functions args

Tags: scala

```
var arr = new Array(3)

returns type of Nothing.

arr(0)="Hi"
```

throws error. I understand that Nothing is not a super type of String.

Why is it not returning Something in java like Object which is super class for all the instances. So that I can assign any type of values in it.

Am I misunderstanding type inference here? Why is it happening?. Is it purposefully implemented in that way?

Note: I use Java extensively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of type inference is specified in https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#local-type-inference.

In this case: The array constructor needs a type parameter, i.e. it's really a `new Array[A?](3)` for some unknown `A?`. The compiler doesn't have any constraints on `A?` at all: it could be anything (it can't use the information from `arr(0)="Hi"` below, which would add a constraint). And `Array` is invariant. In this case the rules say the compiler is supposed to pick the minimal type which satisfies the constraints; that's `Nothing`, because every type satisfies the (lack of) constraints and `Nothing` is the minimal type of all.

You can fix this by giving an expected type

```
val arr: Array[String] = new Array(3)
```

or specifying the type parameter

```
val arr = new Array[String](3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the array type to create. This leaves the compiler to figure out the type.

The compiler only has two options: `Any` or `Nothing`. It attempts to select the most specific type that satisfies the constraints you specified. Since `Nothing` is more specific than `Any`, `Nothing` is selected. Fixing this is simple enough.

Note that even `java.lang.Object` is more specific than `Any` - after all, `Any` may even be a primitive like `Int`.

Comment: It has all possible types as options, not just `Any` and `Nothing`.

Comment: Good point, I was considering the two potential "logical" types, but of course any other type is a potential match too.

Answer (score 0):

For the example you mentioned, the behaviour is similar when it comes to Scala and Java.

```
scala> var arr = new Array(3)
arr: Array[Nothing] = Array(null, null, null)
```

`arr` is of type `Array[Nothing]`. So any read or write to `arr` should be a `Nothing` type. And hence below is a compile time error:

```
arr(0) = "Hi"
Expression of type String doesn't conform to expected type Nothing
```

And:

```
var t: Nothing = arr(0)
```

`t` strictly has to be `Nothing` or a subtype of it. This is the same behavior in Java as well:

```
Nothing$[] arr = new Nothing$[3];
arr[0] = "hi"; //compile time error
```

[This](http://purijatin.github.io/newsletters/generics/) gives deeper insights on variance.

---

If your question is:

In `var arr = new Array(3)`, why is `arr` of type `Array[Nothing]` instead of `Array[Any]`?

Because the compiler needs to infer the best possible type. And it does it by following the `LUB (Least Upper Bound)` strategy. `Nothing` is the least upper bound in  this case.